# Customize table data width html

Tags: html, iframe, html-table

I'm using a table to insert two iframes side by side. Content is is the td, and I'm wondering if I can customize the width (i.e. 30% & 70%)? It looks like the width is split in the middle, if I used the width="70%" for instance, then the iframe gets adjusted inside what looks to be half of the table data.

This doesn't work:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="30%"><iframe..... etx.></iframe></td>
    <td width="70%">iframe......etc.></iframe></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I would not use a table for the sole purpose to position the iframes. Try using the float: left and float:right CSS properties instead? then set the width on the iframes themselves?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is generally considered bad practice to use `table` elements for anything other then displaying tabular data (e.g. layout purposes), so unless the `iframe` elements are actually going to contain tabular data, it's best to use a different approach. Also, the `width` attribute is obsolete in the latest standard, so you should use CSS to specify widths instead.

As for your question, here is a solution that seemed to work in my tests:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <iframe id="iframe2"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#div2, #div3 {
  display: table-cell;
}

#div2 {
  width: 30%;
}

#div3 {
  width: 70%;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This solution uses the `table` and `table-cell` values for the `display` property rather than actual `table` and `td` elements so that the HTML remains semantically correct (that is, it accurately describes the content).

For the sake of completeness, I will add that, if you were actually trying to display tabular data, similar CSS rules could be used to achieve the same effect with actual `table` and `td` elements:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </td>
    <td id="td2">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

#td1 {
  width: 30%;
}

#td2 {
  width: 70%;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Okay I'll try that method w/o using tables, thanks for the advice.

Comment: So I've tried this, and it's stacking the iframes on top of each other, not side by side? Should I try the float left and float right?

Comment: @user2981194 Hmmm, what browser did you use to test it?

Comment: @user2981194 I just re-tested it directly from my answer in multiple browsers and it worked fine for me. It sounds like there might be other confounding factors involved in your code. Could you maybe update your question with more of your code, specifically any other CSS involved?

Comment: I started fresh, and it is working now. I'll keep adding to it and see if I can find out what was screwing things up, likely an error I made. Thanks for the assistance.